# maintain state of dropdownlist in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I maintain the selected value of dropdownlist in MVC3?

I'm using the following code to create the drop down list:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("PEDropDown", 
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PEDropDown"], 
        new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Screener/Screener';this.form.submit();" }
)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example, I use. I am not sure, this is the way you use to populate the DropDownList

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ddlCategories", IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PEDropDown"], "CategoryId", "CategoryName", Model.CategoryId), "Select Category", new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Screener/Screener';this.form.submit();"})%>
```

Another way is, make a select list in controller as follows

```
List<SelectListItem> CategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var item in Categories)
                {

                    CategoryList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Selected = Model.CategoryId, 
                        Text = item.CategoryName, Value = Convert.ToString(item.CategoryId) });
                }
ViewData["PEDropDown"]=CategoryList;
```

and use in view as

```
<%:Html.DropDownList("ddlCategories",IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["PEDropDown"], "CategoryId", "CategoryName", new { onchange = "this.form.action='/Screener/Screener';this.form.submit();"})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I get what you want to do, but I assume you want to get the selected value from the dropdown list?

In that case:

```
new { onchange = "alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" }
```

I put it in an alert for now, because I don't know what you want to do with the value

Comment: The problem is after the value is selected from a dropdown a post method is called and thus it loses its selected value

Answer (score 0):

pass the value back into your controller and then populate a List of SelectListItems in the controller:

```
public actionresult yourmethod (int idToPass)
{

List<SelectListItem> SLIList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (Model model in dropdownList)
{
   SelectListItem SLI = new SelectListItem();
   SLI.text = model.CategoryName;
   SLI.selected = model.CategoryId == idToPass;
   SLIList.Add(SLI);
}
   ViewData["myDDL"] = SLIList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. 
**Using ViewBag instead of ViewData (I suggest, it is better to use Model object)**

```
Html.DropDownList("PEDropDown", new SelectList(ViewBag.PEDropDown, "Key", "Value", Model.PEDropDownSelectedValue), new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/ControllerName/ActionMethod?selectedValue=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" }))
```

The fourth argument in **SelectList** is the selected value. It must be passed using the model object.
When you call the particular action method, set the model object as below.

```
public ActionResult ActionMethod(string selectedValue)
{
    ViewModelPE objModel = new ViewModelPE();
    // populate the dropdown, since you lost the list in Viewbag
    ViewBag.PEDropDown = functionReturningListPEDropDown();
    objModel.PEDropDownSelectedValue = selectedValue;
    return View(objModel);
    // You may use the model object to pass the list too instead of ViewBag (ViewData in your case)
}
```